# invalid syntax error while reading text file

Tags: printing

trying to write and read.
Text is written in the file but while reading I get "invalid syntax" on the print line:
Thank you

```
text_file = open ("write_to_file.txt", "w")

t = input( "enter name ")
a = input ("address ")
enter code here`n =input ("number ")
text_file.write(t)
text_file.write(a)
text_file.write(n)
text_file.close()

text_file = open("write_to_file.txt", "r")
print text_file.read()
text_file.close()
```

Comment: Are you using python 3? In python 3, `print` is a function, so it needs parentheses around its arguments.

Comment: Thank you. With parentheses it works. I am using python 3